Error implementing a python IDropTarget wrapper for Flet
I'm trying to create a wrapper around the IDropTarget to be able to drag and drop files directly into a flet windows app.
This is my current implementation, i'm using pythoncom, win32 API, ctypes:
import pythoncom
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
from ctypes import windll, create_unicode_buffer
import flet as ft
import threading
import time


class IDropTarget:
    _public_methods_ = ["DragEnter", "DragOver", "DragLeave", "Drop"]
    _com_interfaces_ = [pythoncom.IID_IDropTarget]

    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        print("IDropTarget initialized")

    def DragEnter(self, dataObject, keyState, point, effect):
        effect[0] = pythoncom.DROPEFFECT_COPY
        print("DragEnter")
        return 0

    def DragOver(self, keyState, point, effect):
        effect[0] = pythoncom.DROPEFFECT_COPY
        print("DragOver")
        return 0

    def DragLeave(self):
        print("DragLeave")
        return 0

    def Drop(self, dataObject, keyState, point, effect):
        format_etc = pythoncom.FormatEtc(
            pythoncom.CF_HDROP,
            None,
            pythoncom.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
            -1,
            pythoncom.TYMED_HGLOBAL,
        )
        stgmedium = dataObject.GetData(format_etc)
        data = stgmedium.data
        num_files = windll.shell32.DragQueryFileW(data, -1, None, 0)
        file_list = []
        for i in range(num_files):
            length = windll.shell32.DragQueryFileW(data, i, None, 0)
            buffer = create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
            windll.shell32.DragQueryFileW(data, i, buffer, length + 1)
            file_list.append(buffer.value)
        self.callback(file_list)
        print("Drop", file_list)
        return 0


def register_drop_target(hwnd, callback):
    drop_target = IDropTarget(callback)
    drop_target_ptr = pythoncom.WrapObject(
        drop_target, pythoncom.IID_IDropTarget, pythoncom.IID_IDropTarget
    )
    pythoncom.RegisterDragDrop(hwnd, drop_target_ptr)
    print("Drop target registered")


def find_window_by_title(title):
    def enum_windows_proc(hwnd, lParam):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and title in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            lParam.append(hwnd)
        return True

    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_windows_proc, hwnds)
    return hwnds[0] if hwnds else None


def handle_drop(files):
    for file in files:
        print(f"File dropped: {file}")


def poll_for_window_handle(title, callback):
    hwnd = None
    while hwnd is None:
        hwnd = find_window_by_title(title)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Sleep for 100 ms before trying again
    callback(hwnd)


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "dnd"

    page.add(ft.Text("Drag and Drop files here"))

    def on_window_handle_found(hwnd):
        def run_drop_target():
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            try:
                register_drop_target(hwnd, handle_drop)
                pythoncom.PumpMessages()
            except pythoncom.com_error as e:
                print(f"Error registering drop target: {e}")
            finally:
                pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

        thread = threading.Thread(target=run_drop_target)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    poll_for_window_handle(page.title, on_window_handle_found)

    page.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)

This doesnt work, I always get this error back:
Error registering drop target: (-2147024882, "Insufficient memory resources available to complete the operation.", None, None)

Moreover the drag DROPEFFECTs doesn't even seems to be applied.
I don't understand where and what I'm doing wrong, my machine really shouldn't run into a "insufficient resources".
How can I fix it?

RegisterDragDrop: "If you use CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx instead of OleInitialize to initialize COM, RegisterDragDrop will always return an E_OUTOFMEMORY error."

@IInspectable Thanks! it worked! But I still cannot drop files in the target hwnd.  There are no errors, the drop target is registered but the dropeffects aren't working and I cannot drop files in the window. Do you have any idea on why this is happening?

You are probably trying to register the drop target for a window owned by a thread other than the calling thread. Plus, you aren't dispatching messages on the calling thread either (as explicitly pointed out in the documentation).
